# Route did not stabilize in expected time The following resource(s) failed to create NATRoute . Rollback requested by user

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create CloudFormation Stack that will create VPC, Subnets, IGW, Route Tables, NAT Gateway, Associate Subnets with RTs etc

My Stack is failing where NAT Gateway is trying to create Rule for Private Route Table to create Route Rule for NAT GW.

```
  # Punblic Elastic IP for NAT Gateway in Zone 2A
  eipSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc  

  # NAT Gateway in Public Subnet 2A
  natSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId:
        Fn::GetAtt: [eipSubnetA, AllocationId]
      SubnetId:
        Ref: PRODSubnetPublic2a
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: nat-Subnet-a
  # Route through NAT Gateway
  NATRoute:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Route
      Properties:
        RouteTableId:
          Ref: PRODRTPrivate
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        GatewayId:
          Ref: natSubnetA
```

Error I am seeing in the CloudFormation Events tab is:

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [NATRoute]. . Rollback requested by user

Route did not stabilize in expected time
```

Not sure what am I missing?

```
# Private Subnets to Route Table Association      
  PrivateSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId:
        Ref: PRODSubnetPrivate2a
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: PRODRTPrivate
  PrivateSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId:
        Ref: PRODSubnetPrivate2b
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: PRODRTPrivate      
  # Punblic Elastic IP for NAT Gateway in Zone 2A
  eipSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc 
  # NAT Gateway in Public Subnet 2A
  natSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId:
        Fn::GetAtt: [eipSubnetA, AllocationId]
      SubnetId:
        Ref: PRODSubnetPublic2a
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: nat-Subnet-a
  # Route through NAT Gateway
  NATRoute:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Route
      Properties:
        RouteTableId:
          Ref: PRODRTPrivate
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        GatewayId:
          Ref: natSubnetA
```

I expect Private Route Table should have Route NATGateway for Destination 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: All the other resources are created successfully? Remember that your cloudformation template may require a logical order of the resources creation adding DependsOn attribute you can do that a resources depend on the creation of other. For example first you need created the natSubnetA resource before create the NATRoute

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the mistake I made, resolved it by replacing GatewayId: to **NatGatewayId**:

Comment: Saved the day for me!  Was doing the same thing.